# Flutter curl POST request

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am facing issue when sending POST request in FLutter by transforming curl into JSON. I am new to Flutter and I am trying to send data to the internet. Here is my curl:

```
curl -X POST http://my-server/api/order \
    -d api_key='My API key' \
    -d phone='Mobile Phone' \
    -d street='Street Name'\
    -d moderation_required=no
```

and here is my Flutter code which I have written:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'model/orderTaxi_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Data> createOrder(String street) async {
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/order',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'api_key': 'My api Key',
      'phone': '1234',
      'street': street,
      'moderation_required': 'yes',
    }),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    return Data.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to order Taxi');
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  Future<Data> _futureOrder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Post Request'),
      ),
      body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: (_futureOrder == null)
              ? Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      controller: _controller,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Street'),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Place Order'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _futureOrder = createOrder(_controller.text);
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                )
              : FutureBuilder<Data>(
                  future: _futureOrder,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Text(snapshot.data.phone);
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                    }
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                )),
    );
  }
}
```

As my reference, I am using this website https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data.
I will appreciate it if anyone could assist me to solve this issue. I don't know where I am doing a mistake. Maybe my mistake is when I am transforming HTTP.Response to dart object ?

Comment: Could you please edit your post by adding the error you are facing?

Comment: The code is running, however Future function createOrder is throwing Exception 'Failed to order Taxi'. I have a feeling that there is problem with Future function I have written. Based on crul I provided can you help me to transform it to Model Class or how would you convert crul in Flutter ? What would you suggest ?

Comment: Then before throwing the exception, print the response.body and the status code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In curl `-d` means a url encoded form parameter. In your Dart code, you are instead sending a JSON string.

Remove all references to JSON and let the http client encode the form (which it will do if you pass in a `Map<String, String>`.

```
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    'http://xxx.yyy/api/order',
    headers: <String, String>{
      // no! let http set the content type itself -'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: <String, String>{
      'api_key': 'My api Key',
      'phone': '1234',
      'street': street,
      'moderation_required': 'yes',
    },
  );
```